# Swift compare fails with casted variables

Tags: swift, casting, comparison

Background: Creating a forth interpreter in Swift. Hence linked lists containing many different types of items create a lot of casting. Following problem.
NOTE: 'Item' is a longer statement getting the value off a stack.

All three if's return false and so no debug print:-

```
let value1 : Double = Item as! Double
let value2 : Double = Item as! Double
if value1 < value2  { print ("Its less") }
if value1 > value2  { print ("Its more") }
if value1 == value2 { print ("its equal") }
```

However, if I set the values using an intermediate variable it works. :-

```
let fred : Double = Item as! Double
let mike : Double = Item as! Double
let value1 = fred
let value2 = mike
```

Insight into this would be helpful. In the first case, I assume the compiler/swift is maintaining further non-visible information that causes the comparison tests to fail.

Comment: I can't make it fail using anything that can be cast as a Double, and I don't understand how it can fail.  If the cast works it's a double and should be comparable, if it doesn't it'll error.  Out of interest, what type is Item ?

Comment: Can you post a link to a complete, reproducible example? (This sounds like either an error of understanding or a legit compiler error.)

Comment: OK I will try and build an example. The 'Item" is a call to my stack 'pop' routine that returns a Holder<T> object that contains the equivalent of a 'union' in other languages. It  extracts the data from the Holder object which I then cast to a Double (and crash if it isn't). The problem is it both Compiles and Runs. I only found it by detailed testing.